# Transformation of an array of identifiers into elements with additional fields

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

for each `claimNumbers` I want to generate the below expected output from the sample input shared below.

Input payload:

```
{
  "contactUpdateData": [
    {
      "claimNumbers": [
        "12345",
        "12346"
      ],
      "channel": "Agent",
      "updateData": {
        "customer": {
          "customerType": "individual",
          "address": {
            "Line1": "abc"
          }
        },
        "contactpeople": [
          {
            "contactPersonType": "nominee"
          }
        ],
        "reportingfields": {
          "schemetype": "pws"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Output Payload:

```
{
   "contactUpdateData":[
      {
         "cNumbers":"12345",
         "channel":"Agent",
         "updateData":{
            "customer":{
               "customerType":"abcde",
               "address":{
                  "Line1":"abc"
               }
            },
            "contactpeople":[
               {
                  "contactPersonType":"nominee"
               }
            ],
            "reportingfields":{
               "schemetype":"pws"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "claimNumbers":"12346",
         "channel":"Agent",
         "updateData":{
            "customer":{
               "customerType":"individual",
               "address":{
                  "Line1":"abc"
               }
            },
            "contactpeople":[
               {
                  "contactPersonType":"nominee"
               }
            ],
            "reportingfields":{
               "schemetype":"pws"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to understand how we can achieve in Mule 4 using foreach and DataWeave.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try like below:

Map through each claimNumbers with a nested loop.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---

  contactUpdateData: flatten(payload.contactUpdateData map  // loop through entire payload under contactUpdateData
  ($.claimNumbers map (item, index) -> { // loop through each claimNumbers within contactUpdateData
    cNumbers: item,  // transform and map through claimNumbers
    ($ - "claimNumbers") // remove claimNumbers and maps the rest 
  }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below script will help you.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
contactUpdateData : flatten (payload.contactUpdateData map ((item, index) -> 
    item.claimNumbers map (
        {cNumbers: $} ++ (item - "claimNumbers")

    ))
)
```

Comment: You may also use `flatMap` directly instead of flatten + map to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will keep it in my mind.